# Google Cloud Datastore - Endpoint Read Failed Error

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I keep getting below error every once in a while when I call the datastore.save method:

Error: Endpoint read failed at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js

My code is running inside a Google Cloud Function and I am using the official Node.js client library provided by Google for Google Cloud Datastore.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: I'm also getting this error sometimes when calling datastore from my cloud functions.

Comment: There's an open issue for this. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2438

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this appears to be an instance of [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2438). That issue has since been closed because a change in the gRPC library should fix the problem.